# German Residence Permit: Extending it for a University Application Period

Tags: germany, resident-permit, student-visa, residence-cards

I am an Indian undergraduate student living in Germany, and I came here to work on a research project which my undergraduate thesis is based on. My home university, however, is in India and I graduate from that program in June. Naturally, the residence permit I initially applied for was intended to suit that period and, therefore, expires on 30th June.

Meanwhile, I have applied to a few Master programs at German universities and given their reputation and generous fee structures, I am tempted to join one if the offer suits my circumstances. However, given that most universities only declare their results in July, I would not be absolutely certain about such a choice before my residence permit expires in June.

As it stands right now, I already have an offer from Humboldt University in Berlin, and if no better offers show up, I am likely to accept it. Given this situation, I **would like to extend my permit *in my current city of residence***, while I wait for some other results and ready an accommodation arrangement in Berlin, or whichever city I may later move to.

**QUESTION: Can I do so on the basis of my acceptance letter from Humboldt University (and proofs of other applications)?** I am unsure how the rules or provisions within the German immigration code work for a situation like this, so any leads would be much appreciated!

PS: Please note that during this time, I plan to **maintain my current residence**. The **period of this "transitional" extension** would be no longer than 90 days, in any case.

Comment: At least you can go to the local immigration agency and ask them, explaining the situation.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Did you contact your local agency? Maybe you could come back to post an answer helping future users in the same situation.